# Onclick Conversion Tracking with Google Analytics and target=blank

Tags: javascript, google-analytics, window.location

I've just set up onclick google conversion tracking on my site using the js code snippets that google provides. One issue that I am having is that the links are outbound and should open in a new window, hence I use target=blank.

However, one snippet of the google script contains a window.location instruction that redirects the original page that is linked to as well, so I end up with two windows showing the same page.

```
/* <![CDATA[ */
goog_snippet_vars = function() {
 var w = window;
 w.google_conversion_id = 12345;
 w.google_conversion_label = "asdKLAJSDasdkjasd";
 w.google_remarketing_only = false;
}
// DO NOT CHANGE THE CODE BELOW.
goog_report_conversion = function(url) {
 goog_snippet_vars();
 window.google_conversion_format = "3";
 window.google_is_call = true;
 var opt = new Object();
 opt.onload_callback = function() {
  if (typeof(url) != 'undefined') {
   window.location = url;
  }  
 }
 var conv_handler = window['google_trackConversion'];
 if (typeof(conv_handler) == 'function') {
  conv_handler(opt);
 }
}
/* ]]> */
```

Now I would intuitively simply comment out

```
//window.location = url;
```

But the code explicitly states not to change it. So here's my real question: Can this break anything? Is there any reason the outbound page needs to open in the same tab in order for Google Analytics to work properly? (Doesn't seem like it to me) If so, is there a better way?

(I'm aware that I could just try it and see if it breaks but since GA can take up to 48 hours to update I thought I'd ask and see if I can tackle this right away.)

Thanks!